# numpy.array() return [list() list() list()]

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a numpy array from a list with the code like this:

```
def NDDTabel_new(arr_x,arr_y):
    Tabel = [[]]
    for column in range(1,len(arr_x)+1):
        Tabel.append([])
        for row in range(column-1,len(arr_x)+1):
            Tabel[column].append("")
        Tabel[0]=["x","f(x)"]
        for i in range(2,len(Tabel)):
            Tabel[0].append("DD"+str(i-1))
        for i in range(len(arr_x)):
            Tabel[i+1][0]=arr_x[i]
            Tabel[i+1][1]=arr_y[i]
        for i in range(1,len(arr_x)):
            for j in range(1,len(Tabel)-1):
                Tabel[j][i+1]=(Tabel[j+1][i]-Tabel[j][i])/(Tabel[j+1][0]-Tabel[j][0])
    return Tabel
```

After calling the function, the result is:

```
[list([1, 2, 3]) list([-2.0, 1.0]) list([-1.5])]
```

I want it to be:

```
[[1 2 3]
[-2.0 1.0]
[-1.5]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: i think that may just be a display artifact... not sure where you are getting that output display, but those look like the lists you asked it to create. but you aren't creating numpy arrays, you are creating normal python dictionaries. maybe be more clear about what you want to see?

Comment: You can't make a 2d array with lists that differ in size.  What you get is an object dtype array, very much like a list of lists.